# Operator norm of Linear Functionals

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $v = (5,-3,0,0,0,\dots) \in \ell_2$ and let $G:\ell_2\to\mathbb{R}$ be the functional
\begin{equation*}
 G:x\mapsto \langle v,x \rangle
\end{equation*}

a) Calculate the operator norm of $G$ with respect to the norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_\infty$ on $\ell_2$.

b) Find $\Vert G \Vert$ with respect to $\Vert\cdot \Vert_2$ on $\ell_2$.

**My Attempts**

**a)** I took the supremum of $5+3$ and my answer was 8,

**b)** \begin{equation*}
\Vert G \Vert_2^2 = 5^2|x_1|^2+(-3)^2|x_2|^2 +0+0 +\cdots 
\end{equation*}
hence concluded that $\Vert G \Vert_2 = \sqrt{25+9}=\sqrt{34}$.

Can I get help with this question, I am not sure whether I understood it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should remind yourself the definition of operator norm. Well operator norm is $$ ||G||=\sup_{||x||=1}||G(x)|| $$

**a)** This part is true. Because $x=(1,1,0,0,0,...)$ belongs to $\ell_2$ and $||x||_\infty=1$.

**b)** What you wrote is correct but you happen to take $|x_1|^2=|x_2|^2=1$. This can not be the case since you need $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ to have norm $1$, i.e. $|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2$ should be $1$.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, is there anything that I should change?